# Request scope being initialised multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot web application and I have a request scoped bean.

I am using spring security, and need access to the request scoped bean in the filter chain (pre `DispatcherServlet`), so I have registered the `RequestContextListener` to make it available - which all works fine: I can autowire the request scoped bean into my filter chain and use it ok. However, it seems like the request scoped bean is being re-initialised after the spring security filter chain.

Logs below:

```
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/app/test'; against '/logout'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SystemSecurityFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/app/test'; against '/________site-memory-status'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/app/test'; against '/________site-monitor'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestScopeFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.requestScopedBean'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'application'
May 18 06:19:40 INFO  [com.test.app] Creating RequestScopedBean.
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.requestScopedBean'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy] Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /app/test; Attributes: [permitAll]
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter, returned: 1
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] Authorization successful
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /app/test reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
May 18 06:19:40 INFO  [com.test.app] Creating RequestScopedBean.
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/app/test]
May 18 06:19:40 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'AppController'
```

You will see the line "Creating RequestScopedBean" - this is logged in the constructor of my request scoped bean, and is called twice - once at the point that my custom filter is invoked (`RequestScopeFilter`) and then again after the filter chain before hand off to the `DispatchServlet`.  Is this expected behaviour?   Seems strange for it to be available earlier, but then still get re-initialised at `DispatcherServlet` - assumed it would just be configurable, but couldn't see any options on the RequestContextListener.  Thought maybe I should swap to the `RequestContextFilter` and use the `setThreadContextInheritable` method to see if that achieves what I want, but couldn't find any definitive advice on when to use one over the other.

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, this is the second time in a week I have been an idiot on SO - it wasnt actually Spring initialising the bean twice, it was my filter being executed twice and the changes I was making to the request scoped bean was logging the same message.

Next question is why is the filter executing twice? My only guess is because I have registered the filter as both a Spring `@Bean` and added it explicitly to my Spring filter chain. Should I just change to implement `OncePerRequestFilter` or is there some other config to stop it being executed aside from as part of my Spring Security filter chain?

Comment: What is stranger is that first line is called for a bean creation (between *Creating instance* and *Finished creating instance*), while the other is not. But without knowing what is RequestScopeFilter or RequestScopedBean I cannot say more.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta - I have updated question, was largely my error, but has lead to another question now..

Comment: If you added it as a `@Bean` spring boot will detect it and register it as a regular filter, now if you also add it to the spring security chain it will execute twice. Easiest is to remove the `@Bean` annotation.

Comment: I needed to autowire in my request scoped bean to the filter, and that wasn't working if the filter wasnt registered as a bean.  I have changed to extend OncePerRequestFilter and that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the fact that I has initialising the request scoped bean explicitly in the filter (I was setting some state specific to the request in the bean) and that was stupidly logging the same message.

The underlying cause was my Filter was being executed twice, once as part of the Spring Security chain and then again by Spring as I had also registered the Filter as a Spring bean so was automatically added as a normal Filter too.